# Storybook webpack will not load scss files

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, sass, storybook

I'm not getting an error when I run storybook but none of my styles are loading. Please help. I'm using webpack 2.2.1.

I've looked at all of the S.O. and countless G.H. issues answers to no avail. Here's my webpack.config.js within my .storybook directory

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
          {
            test: /\.jsx?$/,
            exclude: /(node_modules|bower_components)/,
            loader: 'babel-loader'
          },
          {
            test: /\.scss$/,
            use: [
              'style-loader',
              'css-loader',
              'sass-loader'
            ],
            include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/styles')
          },
          {
            test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2|svg)$/,
            loader: 'file-loader'
          }
        ]
    }
}
```

Here is my index.html within my stories directory:

```js
import React from 'react';

import { storiesOf } from '@storybook/react';
import { action } from '@storybook/addon-actions';
import { linkTo } from '@storybook/addon-links';
import MenuOption from '../client/app/landingPage/components/menuOption'

import { Button, Welcome } from '@storybook/react/demo';
import { withInfo } from '@storybook/addon-info';
import '../client/styles/index.scss';


storiesOf('Welcome', module).add('to Storybook', () => <Welcome showApp={linkTo('Button')} />);

storiesOf('Component', module)
  .add('simple info',
    withInfo({
      text: 'String or React Element with docs about my component',
    })(() =>
    <MenuOption
      icon={'icon-knife'}
      text={"Orders to Cut Today"}
      isDisabled={false}
      isFocused={true}/>
    )
  )
```

And here is my index.scss:

```css
@import "basic";
@import "icons";
@import "_colors";
@import "_orders";
@import "_header";
@import "_navigation";
@import "_footer";
@import "_key-specification";
@import "_table-summary";
@import "_landing-page";
@import "_order-to-pack";
@import "_error";
@import "_instruction";
@import "_packed-boxes-table";
@import "_source-meat";
@import "_portion-sizes-table";
@import "_byproduct";
@import "components/index";
```

Comment: To debug it easier I would first set webpack output to verbose https://webpack.js.org/configuration/stats/ . That you will be able to see the modules loaded and files output. And please at know the webpack log if it still doesn't work, thanks

Comment: I tried adding stats: "verbose", to my webpack config and nothing changed in the output. @DanielKhoroshko

Comment: I've answered below

Comment: Were you able to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Probably this should help

```
const genDefaultConfig = require('@storybook/react/dist/server/config/defaults/webpack.config.js');

module.exports = (baseConfig, env) => {
  const config = genDefaultConfig(baseConfig, env);

  config.module.rules.push({
     test: /\.scss$/,
     use: [
       'style-loader',
       'css-loader',
       'sass-loader'
     ],
     include: path.resolve(__dirname, '../client/styles')
  });

  config.stats = 'verbose';

  config.resolve.extensions.push('.scss');

  return config;
};
```

Comment: No luck. Still getting the same output (shown below) and the css is not getting loaded :(


ums-ui@0.0.1 storybook /Users/cperson/development/sysco/prime/prime-ui
> start-storybook -p 9001 -c .storybook

info @storybook/react v3.3.5
info
Failed to load ./.env.
info => Loading custom .babelrc
info => Loading custom webpack config (full-control mode).
webpack built 3a246797f12236605fda in 4434ms
info Storybook started on => http://localhost:9001/
info

Comment: Hi! at least there is definitely some progress, as it says 'Loading custom webpack config (full-control mode)'. But how do you actually can tell that it's not loading? What of you delete 'index.scss', will webpack produce an error? If it will, it means index.scss is loading, just maybe includes are not being included. No errors in paths? If upload it in github at least partially, with storybook config and styles files it would be possible to take a look

Comment: Excellent point. I deleted the index.scss and I got this error: ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./client/styles/index.scss
Module build failed: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/cperson/development/sysco/prime/prime-ui/client/styles/index.scss'

Then that lead me to wonder if it was importing successfully, so I deleted basic.scss and got this error: ERROR in ./node_modules/css-loader!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./client/styles/index.scss
Module build failed:
@import "basic";

Comment: If this is not enough information, I can create a stripped down version of what I've got and put it on github for you! Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Yeah I could take a look

Comment: I had this issue as well and also got blocked. Finally I realised I need to ensure the `include: path.resolve(__dirname, "../../")` setting was referencing the root folder of my project. Hope it helps!